# Canonical URL link

Tags: http, https, seo, canonical-link

I am using a canonical url link

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://test123.com" />
```

to avoid duplicate content issues between http and https versions of a site.
At the moment I have it set up that both the http and https versions have the canonical link in the head section.

Is this correct or should I only have the canonical link in the head section on the https version and nothing on the http version? Or does it matter either way?

(I want bots to index my http version and not my https version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you can set your canonical url in http like so

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://test123.com" />
```

for both http and https.  Bots will be index your http canonical url. If you need https version of that page, you can make a redirect on the http page. If a user goes to `http://test123.com` you can redirect user to https page according to your needs.

Comment: I actually have both http and https versions running. I only want search bots to index the http version. The reason I ask is because I read that canonical url linking is basically a 301 redirect for bots. Therefore if I have the canonical link in the http version aswell its similar to 301 redirecting to itself. Will this do any harm?

Comment: You can solve this by putting http version of canonical url in both http and https version

Comment: Yeah that's my question really. The fact that I have the canonical url in the http version aswell means I am basically pointing the canonical url back onto itself. So for http:// test123.com the canonical url will be <link rel="canonical" href="http://test123.com" />. Will this have any negative impact?

Comment: If your canonical url is same as your current url, do not set canonical url.It will be better for your seo

Comment: I took the canonical link out of the HTTP version on your advice. Thanks. Just for clarity sake, above I meant --- _So for http:// test123.com the canonical url will be <link rel="canonical" href="http:// test123.com"; />._

Comment: @cubuzoa, how will it be better for SEO? Any sources?