# HTTP Cache: multiple URLs point to the same HTML file

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, cachestorage

There are times when multiple URLs point to the same HTML file.

For example, the classic use of the base tag

For example the main page can be in:
https://dom.com/schops/

but the following URLs also direct to that file:

```
https://dom.com/shops/mark1
https://dom.com/shops/mark1/products
https://dom.com/shops/mark3
```

My question is, is there a HTTP cache header or a way to mark that a URL actually has another source URL?

How do you usually solve this problem?

Anyway I am creating my implementation in Cache Storge API, but I would like its behavior to be similar to the standard using the necessary headers when appropriate.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297188/canonical-url-link .

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate it in depth!

What I get to see so far from this tag is that it works fine for Google indexing, but I found no information on how it works with local HTTP.

I would like HTTP to implement a similar value in its headers.

Thanks, again!

Comment: Sorry, I just discovered the HTTP link header.